# C: Preprocessor in Macros?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to use preprocessor keywords inside of a macro? If there is some sort of escape character or something, I am not aware of it.

For example, I want to make a macro that expands to this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("FOO%s","BAR");
#else
    log("FOO%s","BAR");
#endif
```

from this:

```
PRINT("FOO%s","BAR");
```

Is this possible, or am I just crazy (and I will have to type out the preprocessor conditional every time I want to show a debug message)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that directly, no, but you can define the `PRINT` macro differently depending on whether `DEBUG` is defined:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else 
    #define PRINT(...) log(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Comment: Ah. I knew it had to be possible somehow, but I was just looking at the wrong end. Thank you.

Comment: @James McNellis: This will create an error, `PRINT("FOO%s","BAR");` gets expanded to `log("FOO%s","BAR");;`, for example.

Comment: @equality:  C89/90 does not have variadic macros, no.

Comment: @nightcracker - While ugly, that's not by any means an error.

Comment: @nightcracker:  I already noticed that and removed the extraneous `;`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz:  It is error-prone, though.  For example, `if (p) PRINT("%p", p); else PRINT("p is null");` is a compiler error, or if you have nested braceless `if` statements it might end up attaching the `else` to the wrong `if`.

Comment: @James - That's true. I'm not saying it's a good thing to do, just that it's not necessarily an error.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it the other way around:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define PRINT printf
#else
    #define PRINT log
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not crazy, but you're approaching this from the wrong angle. You can't have a macro expand to have more preprocessor arguments, but you can conditionally define a macro based on preprocessor arguments:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define DEBUG_PRINT printf
#else
# define DEBUG_PRINT log
#endif
```

If you have variadic macros, you could do `#define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) func(__VA_ARGS__)` instead. Either way works. The second lets you use function pointers, but I can't imagine why you'd need that for this purpose.